# GRUB unable to boot into nvme

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, grub2

I have the following EFI partitions (from `blkid`):

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="1EED-77FD" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="dbc4195e-bb68-4c68-b0f5-5283571d683b"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="5750-AAC4" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System" PARTUUID="f97644b9-d1db-4912-93a5-e74ee1532393"
```

and the following entries generated by `grub-mkconfig`:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/Archlinux/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

But when I try to boot into the Windows OS, grub throws the following error:

```
error: null src bitmap in grub_video_bitmap_create_scaled. 
error: no such device: 1EED-77FD.
error: file `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootingfw.efi' not found.

Press any key to continue..._
```

Mounting and browsing the partition with that UUID shows the file exists:

```
$ ls -lFh /mnt/win/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
.rwxr-xr-x root root 1.5 MB Sat Dec  7 06:38:48 2019  bootmgfw.efi*
```

This is the entry in grub.cfg file:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-1EED-77FD' {
        savedefault
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  1EED-77FD
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1EED-77FD
        fi
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Why is grub reporting that the device with UUID `1EED-77FD` was not found?

Comment: Does your firmware support NVMe natively (i.e. can your Windows boot straight from the NVMe drive)? Was the NVMe drive already present when you last did `grub-install`?

Comment: @user1686 yes. i can boot to windows when choosing from the bios drive list. and yes, i ran grub install as well as mkconfig just before posting this.

Comment: It may also happen [if GRUB is too old](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209653) (say, 2.02), whereas, say, 2.06 would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?116769-Boot-problem-on-Z390-STRIX-E-after-BIOS-update-(1401)#post798961) on Asus ROG forums helped me:

> I got it to boot by doing the following:
>
> 1. Enabling CSM and setting UEFI for PCIe component
> 2. Disabling fast boot
> 3. unplugging my USB3 backup drive

The CSM module was disabled on my BIOS settings, leading GRUB to not be able to detect the nvme drive at boot time.

After enabling CSM and setting all boot components to UEFI only, I was able to boot to windows from grub.